# Does Arnold say that Hardy is responsible for Ramanujan's untimely death?

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, biography

Vladimir Arnold in his book Yesterday and Long Ago, Springer (2007) writes:

> When I resided at Cambridge as a senior fellow of Trinity College,
> Indian colleagues told  me  some  details  of  Ramanujan's life which
> are  not well  known.
>
> Once  an  Indian  physicist  who  arrived  from  the  USA  visited
> Ramanujan in  Trinity.  The  room  of  his  friend  seemed  too  cold
> for  him,  but  Ramanujan  explained  that  he  felt  cold  only  at
> night - when  there  is  sometimes  frost  in  Cambridge!  The
> visitor  asked  to  be  shown  how  Ramanujan  slept,  and  found
> that  he  slept on blankets  and never  suspected  that he should
> have  covered  himself  with  them  (people in  Madras  never do
> this!).  That  is  why  he  felt  cold,  and  that  is  why  he  got
> ill  (it  seems  that  first  it  was  pneumonia  and  then
> tuberculosis)  and  died  at  a very  young  age.
>
> I  think  that  Hardy's snobbery  and  his  inhuman  behavior  did
> not let him visit  his  sick student, who  lived  in the  same house,
> and  did not let him give  elementary practical  advice. While
> telling me  this  story,  my  Indian  colleagues  tactfully avoided  a
> discussion  of  British customs and  connected the  reason for
> Rarnanujan's  death  with  an  Indian  custom,  according to  which
> his  wife  did  not  follow  him,  but  stayed  in  Madras.  She  was
> supposed  to  take  care  of  her  mother-in-law,  Ramanujan's mother;
> this  duty  was  more  important  than  to  take  care  of her
> husband!  Since  that  time  Indian  students in Cambridge have been telling each
> other  how to make a bed and they do not feel cold anymore.

I have never heard this story before and was really surprised. How reliable are these facts and Arnold's explanations? Are there any other sources that corroborate these facts? Possibly that Indian  physicist mentioned by Arnold did write something about this?

Comment: Probably should be at https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question is suitable for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ but not for MO. Discussing speculations that aren't even remotely related to mathematics research is hardly appropriate.

Comment: I have seen others discuss questions like this on MO.

Comment: Is my reputation too small? Is this the problem?

Comment: @Tyrell please give a specific example of others discussing questions like this on MO.

Comment: And any example more than five years old doesn't count – the site changes over time.

Comment: I agree that this question does not belong to this site. But let me add that what Arnold writes about history is frequently incorrect.